# Simple sum runs endlessly

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, summation

I tried evaluating

```
Sum[-(1/(2 X (-X+vF (I+y) (I T+n β))^3)),{n,-∞,∞},GenerateConditions->False]
```

which did not terminate. Whereas the modified sum

```
Sum[ 1/  ((A + B n)^3),{n,-∞,∞},GenerateConditions->False]
```

gives the right answer.

```
(π^3 Cot[(A π)/B] Csc[(A π)/B]^2)/B^3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) the [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) to the form that you know that Mathematica can handle

```
expr1 = -(1/(2 X (-X + vF (I + y) (I T + n β))^3));

Denominator[expr1] // Collect[#, n] & // Simplify

(* 2 X (-X + I T vF (I + y) + n vF (I + y) β)^3 *)

expr2 = Simplify[expr1, 
  {A == -X + I T vF (I + y), B ==  vF (I + y) β}]

(* -(1/(2 (A + B n)^3 X)) *)

sum = Sum[expr2, {n, -Infinity, Infinity},
   GenerateConditions -> True] /. 
     {A -> -X + I T vF (I + y), B ->  vF (I + y) β}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way is as follows. First, Mathematica possibly uses the formula
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}R(n)=-\pi\sum \text{residue}(\cot(\pi n)R(n)),$$
where a rational function $R(n)$ has no poles on the real integers, and $R(z)=O(z^{-2}),\,z\to\infty$, and the sum in the RHS is taken over all poles of $R(z)$.

Indeed, let us consider  it for "the modified sum" `Sum[ 1/  ((A + B n)^3),{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]`. The command

```
SumConvergence[1/((A + B n)^3), n]
```

produces `B!=0` and we should add the condition `A/B \[NotElement]Integers` since we summarize over `n` from`-Infinity`.
Now

```
-Pi*Residue[Cot[Pi*n]*1/((A + B n)^3), {n, -A/B}, Assumptions -> B != 0 && A/B \[NotElement]Integers]
```

> `-((\[Pi] (-\[Pi]^2 Cot[(A \[Pi])/B] - \[Pi]^2 Cot[(A \[Pi])/B]^3))/B^3 )`

which coincides with the answer in the question.

Now

```
SumConvergence[-1/(2 X (-X + vF (I + y) (I T + n \[Beta]))^3), n]
```

> `vF X (I + y) \[Beta] != 0`

Now we find the only pole by

```
Solve[(-X + vF (I + y) (I* T + n \[Beta])) == 0, n]
```

> `{{n -> (T vF + X - I T vF y)/(vF (I + y) \[Beta])}}`

and find the sum of the series by

```
-Pi*Residue[Cot[n \[Pi]]/(2 X (-X + vF (I + y) (I* T + n \[Beta]))^3), 
{n, (T vF + X - I T vF y)/(vF (I + y) \[Beta])},Assumptions -> vF X (I + y) \[Beta] != 0]
```

> `-((\[Pi] (\[Pi]^2 Cot[(\[Pi] (T vF + X - I T vF y))/( vF (I + y) \[Beta])] + \[Pi]^2 Cot[(\[Pi] (T vF + X -  I T vF y))/(vF (I + y) \[Beta])]^3))/( 2 vF^3 X (I + y)^3 \[Beta]^3))`
> $$ -\frac{\pi  \left(\pi ^2 \cot ^3\left(\frac{\pi  (-i T \text{vF} y+T \text{vF}+X)}{\beta  \text{vF} (y+i)}\right)+\pi ^2 \cot \left(\frac{\pi  (-i T \text{vF} y+T \text{vF}+X)}{\beta  \text{vF} (y+i)}\right)\right)}{2 \beta ^3 \text{vF}^3 X (y+i)^3}$$

Edit. The condition on `A` in line 8.

Comment: It should be noticed that `ResidueSum[Cot[n \[Pi]]/(
 2 X (-X + vF (I + y) (I* T + n \[Beta]))^3), n, 
 Assumptions -> vF X (I + y) \[Beta] != 0]` fails "ResidueSum::npsol: Unable to find the sum of residues of Cot[n \[Pi]]/(2 X (-X+vF (I+y) (I T+n \[Beta]))^3)."

Comment: `ResidueSum[Cot[n \[Pi]]/ (A + n B)^3, n, 
 Assumptions -> B != 0 && A/B \[NotElement] Integers]` also fails: "ResidueSum::npsol: Unable to find the sum of residues of Cot[n \[Pi]]/(A+B n)^3.'. Therefore, Mathematica 13.0 does not apply the formula from my answer.